# How to ensure a minimum recording time in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, audio-recording, recording

I am working on a react native app, at this moment I am using EXPO , and I am using expo-av to record the audio.

I would like to know if it is posible to set a minium recording time. I mean, when the user press the recording button, to automatically maintain the recording going for at least 5 seconds.

If this is not posible, maybe, alert the user to record for longer when the audios are too short.

here is the code for recording:

```
async function startRecording() {
    try {
      console.log('Requesting permissions..');
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      }); 
      console.log('Starting recording..');
      const recording = new Audio.Recording();
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
      await recording.startAsync(); 
      setRecording(recording);
      console.log('Recording started');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    console.log('Stopping recording..');
    setRecording(undefined);
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    const uri = recording.getURI(); 
    console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);
    setPath(uri);
    uploadAudio(uri);
  }
```

the screen display:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title={recording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
        onPress={recording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve that by creating a boolean state and use it to either for alert or disabling the stop function for 5 seconds

**Method 1**

```
...
const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
...
async function startRecording() {
try {
  ...
  setDisable(true)
  setTimeout(() => {
    setDisable(false)
  }, 5000);
...
...
      <Button
        title={recording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
        onPress={recording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
        disabled={disable} // Button will only enabled 5 seconds after recording started
      />
...
```

**Method 2**

```
...
const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
...
async function startRecording() {
try {
  ...
  setDisable(true)
  setTimeout(() => {
    setDisable(false)
  }, 5000);
...
...
async function stopRecording() {
  if(disable){
    Alert.alert('Min 5 Sec Required')
    return;
  }//remaining func will only call if disable is false that is after 5 sec
...
...
```